# Submit FormData via RestAPI using Java to Eloqua

Tags: java, rest, eloqua

I am trying to submit FormData via RestAPI using Java.  I am able to create new contacts with my code, but when I change it up to POST to a form I cannot figure out what the JSON format is supposed to be to populate a form.

Here's the error I receive.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
    https://secure.eloqua.com/API/REST/2.0/data/form/175
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at SaveFormData.main(SaveFormData.java:37)
```

Here is what I am trying.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;


public class SaveFormData {


  public static void main(String[] args) {


  try {
  String authString = "siteid\\username" + ":" + "password";
  String authToken = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(authString.getBytes());      
  String response ="";
  String line;
  String body =     "{\"fieldValues\":[{\"id\":0,\"value\":\"asdfasdf\",\"type\":\"FieldValue\"}],\"type\":\"FormData\"}";

  URL url = new URL("https://secure.eloqua.com/API/REST/2.0/data/form/175");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


  conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authToken);    


  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  final OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
  os.write(body.getBytes());
  os.flush();
  os.close();


  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is));
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
  {
  response += line;
  }       
  rd.close();
  conn.disconnect();


  System.out.println(response);


  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ProtocolException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }


  }


}
```